# Flutter Listview inside of a Card showing extra space at the bottom

Tags: flutter

Why is the `Card` showing extra space at the bottom?
[image]

If I set `itemCount: 0` I get this:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> words = ['hello', 'world', 'flutter'];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Card(
        child: ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            );
          },
          itemCount: words.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(words[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. I've failed to produce the issue from current snippet on chrome

Comment: No luck running flutter clean.

Comment: Do you also get the same ui on web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ListView documentation, it has padding by default. You can disable this behavior with

```
ListView(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
   ...
```

Docs here:

````
/// By default, [ListView] will automatically pad the list's scrollable
/// extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by [MediaQuery]'s
/// padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero [padding] property.
///
/// {@tool snippet}
/// This example uses the default constructor for [ListView] which takes an
/// explicit [List<Widget>] of children. This [ListView]'s children are made up
/// of [Container]s with [Text].
///
/// ![A ListView of 3 amber colored containers with sample text.](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/list_view.png)
///
/// ```dart
/// ListView(
///   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
///   children: <Widget>[
///     Container(
///       height: 50,
///       color: Colors.amber[600],
///       child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
///     ),
///     Container(
///       height: 50,
///       color: Colors.amber[500],
///       child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
///     ),
///     Container(
///       height: 50,
///       color: Colors.amber[100],
///       child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
///     ),
///   ],
/// )
/// ```
````

Comment: Hmm, I've been doing this for a while and I never knew this. Thank you! I have another ListView that looks just fine, but now, after reading your response, I just noticed that I added a Padding widget wayyyy above.